# Xcode 11 use Framework in AppExtension

Tags: frameworks, xcode11, sirikit, app-store-connect, build-settings

I want to create an app with multiple SiriKit-Intents. Some of those need a 3rd party framework which, sadly, I cannot install using spm so I did it quick and dirty and downloaded the latest release and manually imported it into Xcode. And everything worked just fine until I wanted to upload to ASC.

[image: The XC-errors]

That's what it said and I guess the root is in my project settings... There I have the same Framework in both Intent-extensions like I normally do and everything works fine in development but I just can't upload it...

[image: Screenshot of project settings]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm kinda embarrassed but here's how I managed it:
1. Add the Framework to the main app (even tho I don't use or need it there). And make sure it's Embedded & Signed (see 2nd screenshot in question)
2. In the project settings for all extensions which need the framework, make sure the Framework status is: `Do not Embed`.

It's simple and easy if you know what to do....